# Validating a file path is legal in eWAM

Tags: file-handling, ewam

What is the method in `eWAM` which will check if a path `tFileName` is valid?
I tried `CHDIR`, however it is a procedure, is there not a function that returns `Boolean`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous answer works, thank you for that. Here are some more options, for both validating a file and a directory.

```
 ;Validate the that a directory exists at that path.
 function ValidateFileDirectory(path : CString) return Boolean    
   uses wUtil

   var testPath : CString

;Given the path to a directory,it will return True if that directory exists.
;-Test if the path is valid before you write a file.
   testPath = wUtil.FGETDIR(path)
   if testPath = path
      _Result = True
   else
      _Result = False
      Alert(kw_BadPath)
      ;! it will return false if you give it a path to a file, even if the file exists.
   endIf
endFunc 

;Validate that the file exists there.
function ValidateFileExists(path : CString) return Boolean
   uses wUtil

   ;Given the path to a file, returns True if it finds the File.
   ;-test to make sure a file is there before you read,
   ;-test if a file was written.
   if wUtil.FGETNAME(path) <> ''
      _Result = True
   else
      Alert(kw_FileNotFound)
      _Result = False
   endIf
endFunc 

function TestOpenFile(path : CString) return Int4
   uses wUtil

   ;Returns 0 if it doesn't find a file, otherwise it returns a larger int4.  
   _Result = wUtil.T_OPEN(path)
   wUtil.T_CLOSE(_Result)
endFunc
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities.

1. Use F_OPEN to try to open the file (returns 0 if nothing was found, > 0 otherwise). Don't forget to close the handle if it was > 0.

   ```
   var hFile : Int4

   hFile = wUtil.F_OPEN(64, 'D:\DummyFile.txt')
   if hFile > 0
       wUtil.F_CLOSE(hFile)
   endIf
   ```
2. Define an external in a module, wrapping to [PathFileExists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

   ```
   function PathFileExists(pszPath : Pointer) return Boolean external 'Shlwapi.PathFileExistsA'
   ```

   and use it :

   ```
   var res : Boolean
   var path : CString

   path = 'D:\Path\File.ext'
   res = YourModule.PathFileExists(@path)
   ```